# jQuery Flip Effect / getElementById

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, flip

I've been using a flip effect which I want to use for multiple widgets, but I've been struggling with the following problem: I've used the same base HTML for the different widgets. So when I want to flip the first widget on my page, I works just fine. When I want to flip another widget, it doesn't work at all...

I noticed that the problem refers to my scripting. Because I used `document.getElementById`, it only recognises the first unique ID. But now I don't want to change the names of the id's in each different widget. Is their a way to rewrite my script so I can define mutiple id's in it?

**HTML**

```
<section class="widget span3">
   <!--front-->
   <div id="front" class="widget-1-2 flip">
      <div class="widget-header">
         <h2>Monthly Statistics</h2>
         <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button id="btn-front" class="btn"><i class="icon-cogs icon-white" alt="settings"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-minimize"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white" alt="minimize"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-close"><i class="icon-remove icon-white" alt="close"></i></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content"><p>This is the front.</p></div>
   </div><!--/front-->

   <!--back-->
   <div id="back" class="widget-1-2 flip">
      <div class="widget-header">
         <h2>Monthly Statistics / Settings</h2>
         <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button id="btn-back" class="btn"><i class="icon-signal icon-white" alt="charts"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-minimize"><i class="icon-chevron-up icon-white" alt="minimize"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-close"><i class="icon-remove icon-white" alt="close"></i></button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-content"><p>This is the back.</p></div>
   </div><!--/back-->
</section><!--/widget-1-2-->
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
   document.getElementById( 'btn-front' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById( 'back' ).className = 'flip flip-front';
      document.getElementById( 'front' ).className = 'flip flip-back';
   }, false );

   document.getElementById( 'back' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      document.getElementById( 'back' ).className = 'flip';
      document.getElementById( 'front' ).className = 'flip';
   }, false );
</script>
```

For the rotating / flip effect I use CSS.
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element's id attribute is supposed to be a unique identifier in HTML. You're writing incorrect HTML if there is more than one id attribute with the same value on a page.

Give each separate widget a unique identifier and create a function in your JavaScript that takes the widget's id as a parameter. `front`, `back`, `btn-front` and `btn-back`should be classes instead of ids.

Then fetch the widget with `getElementById`, and fetch those classes with `getElementsByClassName` instead. Or use `querySelector`.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply. If I replace the `back` ID and use for example `back-1`, `back-2`, `back-3`, `front-1`, `front-2`, `front-3`, ... as unique ID's, how can I then define them in my JavaScript? Because `getElementById` is for only one ID and I want to define more ID's in it. (`document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't seem to work out for me.)

Comment: Don't enumerate the ids, make them classes instead. The only id you need is the unique identifier for your whole widget (section element). Then you can fetch the whole widget with `getElementById`, say `var widget = document.getElementById("widget-foo")`, and then get that widget's front and back with `widget.getElementsByClassName("front")[0]` for example.

Comment: After you've added the id for the whole widget and changed the existing ids to classes, `document.querySelector("#widget-foo .front")` should work as well.